# Google Script Line Break on Section Header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently creating a line break for Google Script. I managed to create a line break for title and the content inside. However, when I tried to create line break for a new header title. I could not find the attribute or variable for new section title, do anyone know how to call out the variable of it?[image]

As the title in the front can be called using

```
var mainTitle = form.getTitle();
```

and the variable for the text can be called using

```
var title = questions[i].getTitle();
```

Do anyone know the variable of the title for a new section title?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item. If you need further help add a [mcve] showing how are you adding / grabbing the section.

Comment: new section title considered as regular item.  You can get the title using for (i in forms.getItems()){
        console.log(forms.getItems()[i].getTitle())
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a little upon liquidkat's comment, you can check the Google Forms Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item) for this.

The form is composed of *items*. You can get a list by calling [`getItems()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getItems()) on the form.

```
  let myform = FormApp.openById("...")
  let items = myform.getItems() //an array with all the items

  for (i in items){
    console.log(items[i].getTitle()) // will list the titles of all the items
  }
```

To narrow down the search you can also get items by [`itemType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type). Your screenshot seems to be a `PAGE_BREAK` item so here's an example:

```
  let myform = FormApp.openById("...")
  let items = myform.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) //an array with only page breaks
```

Note that retrieving the objects as `Item` only has the properties shared by all item types. If you want to access properties specific to a certain item type you have to cast it to that type. Here's the sample from Google:

```
// Create a new form and add a text item.
var form = FormApp.create('Form Name');
form.addTextItem();

// Access the text item as a generic item.
var items = form.getItems();
var item = items[0];

// Cast the generic item to the text-item class.
if (item.getType() == 'TEXT') {
  var textItem = item.asTextItem();
  textItem.setRequired(false);
}
```

And as you probably noticed, the very first section that the Form starts with doesn't really count as one of the items, and you can check it with `myform.getTitle()`.

**Reference**:

- [Item interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item)
- [List of item types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type)
- [Main Forms documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)